# C++ Check if key is pressed, not held down

Tags: c++, windows, key

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1;) {
        if (GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000)
        {
            cout << "op";
        }
}
```

This prints out `op` if the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is held down, actually it spams the output if you hold down the key.

This is what I want instead:

The program prints out something ONCE when you press/hold down a key instead of spamming it, and the only way to print it again is to let go of the key and press it again. No matter how long you hold down the key, the program will only execute the following code ONCE, unless you press it again.

How do I make my code do this?

Comment: Add a flag and set it when key gets pressed for the first time and unset when key is released. On each key press check this flag to figure out whether key is just pressed or held.

Comment: Or use [`GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293.aspx) instead: "*Determines whether a key is up or down at the time the function is called, **and whether the key was pressed after a previous call to GetAsyncKeyState**.*"

Answer (score 3):

You could simply set a `bool` to `true` when you've detected a "key down" event and then only set it back to `false` once you detect a "key up" event. That way you can know if the key was already down and only report that it was pressed if it was not already in that state.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, it will still spam as long as you hold it down won't it? Can you provide some code maybe?

Comment: @J. Doe sure, Windows will still generate events. The *point* is that you will keep track of the key state, allowing you to say "a key down event occurred, but *ohh* I've already seen one of those without an intermediate key up event, so I'll just ignore this one". You can't really prevent the OS from *generating* the events but you *can* keep track of which ones to act on.

Comment: Alright, sounds good. So I would have to check the current time each time SHIFT is pressed, and then check how long ago the last check was? So how would I do that? I know you can use "CurrentTimeMilis" in Java but in C++ I'm not sure.

Comment: @J. Doe no, no, no. Why are you mixing time into it? It is *really* simple. Just have a flag per key saying if you've already seen a key press event for that key. Set if when you get a press event, clear it when you get a release event. When desiding whether to act on a press event, consider the flag - only act if the flag is not yet set. Don't confuse things by adding timing and other nonsense into the equation. It's just a simple boolean flag.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3JMWD3NB

Something like this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @J.Doe `if (keyPressed = false)` needs to be `if (keyPressed == false)`, or simpler `if (!keyPressed)`