# In Windows, is there a physical memory address that represents the keyboard key presses, which can be accessed by external PCI devices?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, dma

What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
// memory address where the key press information is stored
constexpr void* KEY_PRESS_ADDRESS = reinterpret_cast<void*>(0x123456789);

// format of the data
struct KeyPressData
{
    bool upArrowPressed;
    bool downArrowPressed;
    bool leftArrowPressed;
    bool rightArrowPressed;
    
    // etc..
};

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // read the key press data from memory
        KeyPressData keyPressData;
        std::memcpy(&keyPressData, KEY_PRESS_ADDRESS, sizeof(KeyPressData));

        // check if the up-arrow key is being pressed
        if (keyPressData.upArrowPressed)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code obviously does not work, as it is a concept.

I am trying to do this from an external source, such as a memory controller board. Hence, I need to circumvent the use of normal methods, such as `GetAsyncKeyState()`, etc.

Is it even possible to do this in a safe and reliable way? If so, how?

I realize that the memory address might differ depending on OS version, but is there even a data structure that contains the keypress information in memory? If so, within what section?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Check if key is pressed, not held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225203/c-check-if-key-is-pressed-not-held-down)

Comment: Or use [`GetKeyboardState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardstate) to get the state of all the keys at the same time

Comment: @Julia No, I am not trying to use any GetAsyncKeyState() function or similar. What I want to do is check for keypress state(s) through reading live memory, not even sure if it is possible in a reliable way. Hence the question.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Windows 10 Pro, version: 22H2 (19045.2364)

Comment: The reliable way is to use the functions the API provides. Why do you want to circumvent those functions?

Comment: Ok even on windows there is no "hardware" address to read from. The whole idea of the OS is to hide the hardware details from you (and even preventing you from direct access, except for drivers). So you're "stuck" with what the API provides you. And this should be good enough.

Comment: There is also : [GetAsyncKeyState function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate)

Comment: No. MS-DOS allowed something close to this, but it didn't really support it even then. It was mostly an accidental side-effect of running in x86 real mode, so it had no way to stop you from doing it. But nothing at all recent runs in real mode.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry, should have stated this in the question as well. But I need to circumvent those functions because I am trying to do this externally, from a memory controller board. The code in of itself is only a concept of what I want. So what I am trying to learn is if there is a data struct in memory that " holds " the keypress states.

Comment: @JerryCoffin MS-Dos did not virtualize hardwar. And you had access to all kinds of memory mapped IO (even setting pixels on VGA was through setting memory addresses).
Was kind of fun though :)

Comment: How is the controller board connected to the PC? I cannot imagine it is directly on the memory bus. And if it is you might need a driver to put the information in a bit of shared memory.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I'm not sure if it is a good idea to use `GetKeyboardState`, because the posted program does not seem to be using a message queue, and the function `GetKeyboardState` does not specify the current state of the keyboard, but rather the state of the keyboard at the time of the last keyboard event that was extracted from the message queue.

Comment: @PepijnKramer it is connected through the PCIE interface, it can read basically 99% of the memory.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel _"The status changes as a thread removes keyboard messages from its message queue."_ - Aha... Bummer ...

Comment: I'd imagine the best you can do is have some software/driver that reads the key state and writes it to a fixed address. Windows is almost certainly holding the keyboard state in memory somewhere but I can't imagine it'll tell you where, probably in some random location inside the keyboard driver

Comment: @AndreasWenzel done. Sorry about that, first time asking a question on this place.

Comment: I was about to say something similar. It looks like either a device driver is needed that puts data in memory or a program that polls the keyboard and writes state into a memory buffer. And that memory must be physical addresses not virtual ones. (Never used it but maybe something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-mmallocatecontiguousmemory)... I am brainstorming here

Comment: @AlanBirtles So you don't think there is a reliable method of reading the keyboard state from live windows memory (including kernel)? :/

Reversing the keyboard driver is not really viable and would also just create a big headache if it differs on every keyboard.

Comment: nope, it'd probably cause Microsoft massive headaches to keep the keyboard state at a well know location, just use the APIs provided e.g. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194729/Keyboard-Hooking-In-Kernel

Comment: @AlanBirtles Alright. I guess that is the only realistic way. Thanks for the information regardless!

Comment: There can be multiple keyboards (multiple physical keyboards, plus virtual keyboards created by Remote Desktop) and multiple sessions (each of which has a separate keyboard state). There is no concept of "the" keyboard state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In real mode, the BIOS uses data at 40:17 to store the keyboard flags, and a queue at 40:1E to store data that's been read from the keyboard. But I'm reasonably certain no modern OS uses the BIOS, so that probably doesn't work at all any more (except early in booting, while the BIOS is still active, and the OS hasn't booted yet).

If you want to make this work, you'll probably need to write a device driver (or modify an existing one) to capture the current keyboard state to allow the card to access it. On Windows, the most obvious choice would probably to make it a [keyboard class filter driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-driver-samples/keyboard-input-wdf-filter-driver-kbfiltr/). A keyboard filter driver is given the input from the keyboard so it can do things like ignoring certain input that's not desired. In your case, it'll pass all input through, unchanged--but it'll record the input to memory or (probably preferred) write it to the card.

If you really insist on writing the data to memory, you'll probably need to allocate that memory from the non-paged pool, then write its physical address to some register on the card (or something on that order) so the card will know where to read it. PCI/PCIe cards have a configuration space where you can write data to configure the card, but it's open to question what you'll need to write where to configure whatever card you're dealing with in this case.

Comment: I will try the BIOS, ill get back to you if it works.
But this was extremely helpful information regardless, thanks!